# Is it possible to convert a website to an application or an offline website?

Tags: php, drupal, web-applications, web

I built a website based on Drupal 7. This website has more than 5000 items of content, and is based on PHP with MVC framework, MySQL database and AJAX.

I need to represent this website as a software such that it can be copied on an storage and be used on any computer without internet connection and local webserver (XAMPP, WAMP, etc). Is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: _offline website_? (o.O)"

Comment: Yes it is possible - but it would no longer be a website, you'd have to recreate the whole thing as a software package.

Comment: @diggersworld that is exactly what I want

Comment: So... Its not _offline website_. Even will not be considered _website_. Its just an application installed in PC.

Comment: @bcesars yes I need an application

Comment: Following on from the answer below, you might be able to swap the MySQL database for SQLite, to reduce the complexity of the installed stack. I don't know how well Drupal will run on that, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search of nightrain and phpdesktop-chrome.

phpdesktop-chrome is better than night rain. you just put you code inside the www folder, config the database (I used sqlite) and click in icon to open(you can use composer.json to config you application).

I hope this "off-line server" help you.

Night Rain https://www.naetech.com/php-nightrain

phpdesktop-chrome https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/DownloadChrome

Comment: Does this software process Ajax ?

Comment: @Drupalist He process PHP scripts, is equal xampp. just unzip and run. In my tests run normally. I using CakePHP.